# What is a portable way to list all imports required by a compiled Java class

Tags: java, dependencies, decompiling

I'm looking for a few ideas to quickly generate an list of imports requires by a java class. Ideally this could be done using javap or some other tool found in the JDK.

I'm not interested in a GUI program because eventually I want to use the output for validating my build. Also, I don't want to hook in a large amount of binary code that has to be added into the build code. So the simpler the solution, the better.

Answer (score 3):

This is quick and dirty, but may be *good enough* for what you want. Search for the class constants:

```
>javap -classpath ... -c -private -s -verbose grimbo.appengine.test.perf.Log  | findstr /r /c:"const.#[0-9]*.=.class"
```

Gives:

```
const #3 = class        #38;    //  java/lang/StringBuilder
const #11 = class       #47;    //  grimbo/appengine/test/perf/Log
const #12 = class       #48;    //  java/lang/Object
const #43 = class       #54;    //  javax/servlet/ServletContext
const #45 = class       #56;    //  java/io/PrintWriter
```